# get tag with json ot jsonb query

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I am using PostgreSQL 11.
I'm trying get "wmnote" tag from this json(this is a fragment, it is necessary to close the labels):
{

```
"order": [
    {
        "notes": {
            "note": []
        },
        "onHold": "false",
        "wmnotes": {
            "wmnote": []
        },
        "invoices": {
            "invoiceDetail": []
        },
        "confirmed": "true",
        "enteredBy": "",
        "entryType": "",
        "orderType": "DTC",
        "orderEvent": "Update",
        "orderLines": {
            "orderLine": [
                {
                    "notes": {
                        "note": []
                    },
                    "isGift": "false",
                    "itemID": "4027956",
                    "onHold": "false",
                    "wmnotes": {
                        "wmnote": [
                            {
                                "noteSeq": "1",
                                "noteCode": "",
                                "noteType": "DDate",
                                "visibility": "0",
                                "commentText": "02/07/2019"
                            }
```

This is my query:

```
select o.info->>'order'-> 'orderLines'->'wmnotes'->'wmnote'
            from customer_orders o
            where o.order_id = 1;
```

But result is null.

The column name info is a data type jsonb.

They could help me with the construction of the query!!

Comment: I already answered but for next time: Please always give a working and minimized example! Your sample JSON is not valid (not closed) and it much too big to show your problem. A much more minimized example has been used in my fiddle... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points:

1. `->>` gives out a text not a type JSON. So you would not be able to work with the result as a JSON object. Use `->` instead as you did with all furth steps
2. `order` contains an array. So you have to specify which array element you are searching for. If you want to search the first element you need to call `"order" -> 0 -> "orderlines"` (note JSON arrays are zero based!)
3. `orderline` contains an array as well. See point 2.

So your query should look like:

```
SELECT o.info->'order'->0 -> 'orderLines' -> 'orderLine' -> 0 -> 'wmnotes'->'wmnote'
FROM customer_orders o
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8659d8fc233b1b7ec0f35592109edefe)